# asp .net core api published on iis cause (localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I have published Web API project on IIS

Already tried things:

.Net Core hosting bundle. (added) and I can see it in IIS target website modules.
IIS settings checked many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to inspect your appication pool that is serving your site. Make sure it is not set to .NET framework.

And, please, provide more information when you're posting questions :-)

Comment: thanks for your comment , i'm using migration and i edited the config and now there is new exception 
SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'TimeCheck', database 'CheckTimeDb', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: Then you are using username/password for a user that has limited access to your database. You should really test your app locally first, and not do debugging stuff on server.

Comment: Great. I would approciate if you accept my answer in order to get some creds for the job :-)